# Returning Blank List

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

A little help here please. This is for information purposes only. I'm scraping this site using xpath method from the lxml.html library to return the element that contains what I need. I'm a beginner so after doing some research I figured out using .join, re., split, etc. I can convert into a readable string (my goal is to then transfer all the variables into a csv or excel).

So my issue is string variables saledate1 & saleprice1 is printing no problem, but saledate2 & saleprice2 are not. What is the issue here I don't understand.

Here is the HTML code:

```
 <TD Align="center" >
             <SPAN CLASS = "BodyCopyBold9">
              10/10/2012
              &nbsp;
             </SPAN>
            </TD>
            <TD Align="center" >
             <SPAN CLASS = "BodyCopyBold9">
              SWD-T
              &nbsp;
             </SPAN>
            </TD>
            <TD Align="center" >
             <SPAN CLASS = "BodyCopyBold9">
              $100
             </SPAN>
             &nbsp;
            </TD>
            
             <TD Align="center">
              <A HREF = "https://officialrecords.broward.org/AcclaimWeb/Details/GetDocumentbyBookPage/O/49164/308">
               <SPAN CLASS = "BlueBodyCopyBold9">
                49164&nbsp;/&nbsp;308
               </SPAN>
              </A>
             </TD>
            
           </TR>
          
            <TD Align="center" >
             <SPAN CLASS = "BodyCopyBold9">
              10/12/2012
              &nbsp;
             </SPAN>
            </TD>
            <TD Align="center" >
             <SPAN CLASS = "BodyCopyBold9">
              SWD-D
              &nbsp;
             </SPAN>
            </TD>
            <TD Align="center" >
             <SPAN CLASS = "BodyCopyBold9">
              $400,000
             </SPAN>
             &nbsp;
            </TD>
```

And here is the Python Code:

```
import lxml.html
import re
import requests

data = requests.get("https://bcpa.net/RecInfo.asp?URL_Folio=504201170140").content
htmlelement = lxml.html.fromstring(data)

#Sale Date & Price - Row1 - WORKS
saledate1element = htmlelement.xpath("/html/body/table[2]/tr/td/table/tr[1]/td[1]/table[9]/tr/td[1]/table/tr[3]/td[1]/span/text()")
saleprice1element = htmlelement.xpath("/html/body/table[2]/tr/td/table/tr[1]/td[1]/table[9]/tr/td[1]/table/tr[3]/td[3]/span/text()")
saledate1string = ' '.join(map(str, saledate1element))
saledate1 = " ".join(re.split("\s+", saledate1string , flags=re.UNICODE)).strip()
saleprice1string = ' '.join(map(str, saleprice1element))
saleprice1 = " ".join(re.split("\s+", saleprice1string , flags=re.UNICODE)).strip()
print(saledate1)
print(saleprice1)

#Sale Date & Price - Row2 - DOESNT WORK - Empty?
saledate2element = htmlelement.xpath("/html/body/table[2]/tr/td/table/tr[1]/td[1]/table[9]/tr/td[1]/table/tr[4]/td[1]/span/text()")
saleprice2element = htmlelement.xpath("/html/body/table[2]/tr/td/table/tr[1]/td[1]/table[9]/tr/td[1]/table/tr[4]/td[3]/span/text()")
saledate2string = ' '.join(map(str, saledate2element))
saledate2 = " ".join(re.split("\s+", saledate2string , flags=re.UNICODE)).strip()
saleprice2string = ' '.join(map(str, saleprice2element))
saleprice2 = " ".join(re.split("\s+", saleprice2string , flags=re.UNICODE)).strip()
print(saledate2)
print(saleprice2)
```

The result:

```
C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\scrape\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/scrape/test.py
10/10/2012
$100
```

Fyi, I had to delete /tbody from the Xpath. It seems the browser populates this data in the Xpath even though it isn't in the source code(I read this somewhere, not sure if this is 100% accurate but it worked).

Any help or information leading me in the right direction would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Best,

Newb

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  Where in that block of "magic" abbreviations and operations did the values not match what you expected?

Comment: I edited my message to show what complies after hitting run. I get saledate1 = "10/10/2012" and saleprice1 = "$100" but for saledate2 & saleprice2 I'm getting a blank string

Answer (score 0):

You get blank strings for the output because you have `join`ed empty lists, resulting in empty strings: both `saledate2element` and `saleprice2element` are empty.  You need to use the `lxml.html` methods to work your way down through the path you're using, to find out where it doesn't match what you think is in your loaded structure.

Comment: I know it's resulting in an empty list. That is why I wrote the post and seeking help. I am using lxml.html. Did you look at the code? I use xpath.

Comment: Yes, I looked at your code; I explained the problem you presented. If you know that the lists are empty, that should be reflected in your code.  I requested the SO standard of a MRE, including where you've traced your path.  You haven't done that.  This is still a "magic" path of 15 elements with no intermediate output.